# Zero down-time deployments using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've pulled together a cd solution for my own little personal projects using `docker-compose`, but no matter what I try I have ~10 seconds of down-time every time I redeploy.

My CI service uploads new docker images under certain tags, and then hits a webhook. The webhook triggers the following script:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

**Here is my `docker-compose`:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    image: <image name>/backend:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - back
  static:
    restart: always
    image: <image name>/static:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "7180:80"
    networks:
      - front
      - back

networks:
  front:
  back:
```

The `replicas` seems to be ignored, since I'm not in swarm mode. I'm not 100% sure what swarm mode is. I'm starting to venture into several areas I'm not very comfortable, and thought I'd seek some advice. **What should I do to have zero down-time deployments?**

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose helps you run an image or multiple images by using a yaml file.

Docker swarm or Kubernetes are orchestrators, they organize containers in such a way that is simpler to manage a lot of them.

I have more experience with Kubernetes, and with it you can manage these so called replicas and deployments, and also re-deploy with 0 downtime. Docker swarm should be able to achieve the same.

Comment: I created a swarm on my machine `docker swarm init`, and created a stack - `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml example-staging`. It gets everything running, but I've yet to successfully get it to update to a new image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker swarm for rolling deployments without downtime.